# How can one solve this without expanding.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

\begin{array}{l}
\text { If } a+b+c=1, a b+b c+c a=2 \\
\text { and } a b c=3 \text {. What is the value } \\
\text { of } a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4} \text { ? }
\end{array}

This can be solved by expanding but is there any easy alternative method ?

Here is how I solved :

\begin{array}{l}
(a+b+c)^{2}=1\\
\Rightarrow a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2(a b+b c+c a)=1\\
\Rightarrow a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}=-3 \ldots . .(i)\\
\Rightarrow a b+b c+c a=2 \ldots . \text { (ii) }\\
\text { Squaring of equation (ii), }\\
\Rightarrow a^{2} b^{2}+b^{2} c^{2}+c^{2} a^{2}+2\left(a b^{2} c+b c^{2} a+\right.\\
\left.c a^{2} b\right)=4\\
\Rightarrow a^{2} b^{2}+b^{2} c^{2}+c^{2} a^{2}+2 a b c(a+b+c)=4\\
\Rightarrow a^{2} b^{2}+b^{2} c^{2}+c^{2} a^{2}+6=4
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l}
\Rightarrow a^{2} b^{2}+b^{2} c^{2}+c^{2} a^{2}=-2 \ldots . \text { (iii) }\\
\text { Squaring of equation (i), }\\
\Rightarrow a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}+2\left(a^{2} b^{2}+b^{2} c^{2}+c^{2} a^{2}\right)=9\\
\Rightarrow a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}-4=9\\
\Rightarrow a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}=13
\end{array}

Comment: Please show your working

Comment: 'Easy' is relative and depends on individuals.

Comment: Then I would say a "shorter " method for solving it .

Comment: Please, choose carefully the tags. This is not linear algebra

Comment: @jjagmath sorry.

Comment: @MWD If you are allowed to use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials): $\;p_4=e_1^4-4e_1^2e_2+4e_1e_3+2e_2^2-4e_4$ $= 1-4 \cdot 2 + 4 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 2^2 - 4 \cdot 0 = 13\,$.

Comment: @dxiv That's too high for me . Thanks anyways. BTW what does e represent here.

Comment: @MWD $e_k$ are the expressions you are given, known as the elementary symmetric polynomials. It's all explained at the link in my previous comment, and the formulas can be proved with nothing more than basic algebra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$a,b,c$ are roots of $x^3 - x^2 + 2x-3 = 0$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2 - 2(ab+bc+ac) = 1-2(2)=-3$$

Since
$$x^3 = x^2 -2x+3$$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a^2+b^2+c^2) - 2(a+b+c) + 9 = -3-2(1)+9=4$$

Since
$$x^4 = x^3 -2x^2+3x$$

$$a^4+b^4+c^4 = 4-2(-3)+3(1)=13$$

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for . Thankyou so much Sir . Got it.

Comment: $a,b,c$ satisfies the equation above it, when you sum them up, $3(3)=9$ since there are $3$ copies.

Comment: Yeah just realised thanks